# MySQL - select maximum sum

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table as below.

```
**AuthorID**, **PublicationName**, ReferenceCount, CitationCount
```

AuthorID and PublicationName act as the primary key. I need to find the maximum sum of ReferenceCount and CitationCount for all the authors. For example, the data is as below.

```
1 AAA 2 5
1 BBB 1 3
1 CCC 2 4
2 AAA 1 4
```

In this case, I need my output as,

```
1 AAA 7
2 AAA 5
```

I tried the below query.

```
SELECT AuthorID, PublicationName, Max(Sum(ReferenceCount + CitationCount)) 
from Author 
Group by AuthorID, PublicationName
```

If I use max(sum(ReferenceCount + CitationCount)) group by AuthorID, PublicationName I get an error as "Invalid use of Group function". I believe I should include **Having** clause in my query. But am not sure on how to do the same.

Comment: By the looks of your output, that just looks like the sum to me, and put in order of that sum.

Comment: The MySQL naming convention discourages CamelCase table and field names, instead an underscore should be used to separate words (eg. author_id and publication_name).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question right, you want all the records for the publication that has the most citations.  The publication and their citation counts is given by:

```
SELECT PublicationName, Sum(ReferenceCount + CitationCount)
from Author
Group by PublicationName
order by Sum(ReferenceCount + CitationCount) desc
limit 1;
```

The `order by` and `limit 1` give you the highest value.

If you want all records for the publication with the maximum sum:

```
select a.*
from Author a join
     (SELECT PublicationName, Sum(ReferenceCount + CitationCount)
      from Author
      Group by PublicationName 
      order by Sum(ReferenceCount + CitationCount) desc
      limit 1
     ) asum
     on a.PublicationName = asum.PublicationName
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have 6434 rows in my table. If I run distinct AuthorID query, I get 389 rows. However, if I use the query as you suggested, I am getting the output for just one author ID.

Comment: @Ramesh. . . That usually happens when you leave out a `group by` clause.  However, I modified the answer, because I think I initially misunderstood it.

Comment: I still see output for only one row. I am not sure why it's giving output for only one author ID as I have 389 distinct author ID's in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT AuthorID, PublicationName, Max(ReferenceCount+CitationCount) 
FROM Author 
GROUP BY AuthorID
```

The problem with your query was that the SUM() sums a column's value for many rows. It cannot be used to sum columns the way you wanted. For that, just use the plus (+), normally.